# How to prevent moving WP8 web browser control content sideways?

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, viewport

Could someone help me with some solution that would prevent user from moving WP8 web browser content sideways but still allow to scroll vertically?

Answer (score 1):

use the below meta tag in the web page to avoid sidewise scrolling.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```